# Inserting a few lines of text at the end of a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

My title didn't seem to match questions that may have my answer, and I did find some snippets from other threads/sites to help me get this far. I'm looking for assistance tying the entire macro together. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Test()

Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
Dim oPara1 As Word.Paragraph

Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

Set oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
With oPara1.Range
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    With .Font
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Size = "12"
        .Bold = True
    End With
End With

Selection.TypeText Text:="Fosters, Inc."
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.TypeText Text:="www.genericwebsite.com"
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

'this needs to be left alignment from here on out
Selection.TypeText Text:="Block\Paragraph Format:"
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.TypeText Text:="Run Date:"
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.TypeText Text:="Picture:"
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.TypeText Text:="Symbol:"
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.TypeText Text:="Guest Book:"

End Sub
```

I want it to move to the end of the document and print:

```
                     Fosters, Inc.
                www.genericwebsite.com

Block\Paragraph Format:
Run Date:
Picture:
Symbol:
Guest Book:
```

Thanks for any help - I've spent literally just an hour or so with vba in Word today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
Dim oPara1 As Word.Paragraph

Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

Set oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
With oPara1.Range
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    With .Font
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Size = "12"
        .Bold = True
    End With
End With

Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCr
Selection.TypeText Text:="Fosters, Inc." & vbCr
Selection.TypeText Text:="www.genericwebsite.com" & vbCr
oPara1.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
Selection.TypeText Text:="Block\Paragraph Format:" & vbCr
Selection.TypeText Text:="Run Date:" & vbCr
Selection.TypeText Text:="Picture:" & vbCr
Selection.TypeText Text:="Symbol:" & vbCr
Selection.TypeText Text:="Guest Book:"

End Sub
```

Comment: This works really well - the only minor issue is that we create a new document, whereas I would like it to insert at the end of a document that we're already in.

Comment: Updated it for you to work with the `ActiveDocument`